# Can Anyone help out with Including openssl into my project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, openssl, rsa

I am trying to include the

[4457113 May 10 17:20:24 2012 openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz](http://www.openssl.org/source/)  but I am constantly getting this **Error**

**unable to expand Openssl 1.0.1c.tar.gz into RegisterationMsg
   Error1 =operation not permitted**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're on OSX because this is marked objective-c.  Did you mean to do a

```
tar -xf openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1c
./configure
make
```

first?  I'm not really familiar with iPhone development, but I'm assuming you need to unpack and build the library first.